# How to change AWSTATS configuration via cli

Tags: configuration, apache-2.4, batch-file, batch, awstats

My Apache log files have the date included in the name and I can't change this.  Is there a way to change the `LogFile` config parameter for AWSTATS using Windows CMD prompt?  Better yet a batch script?  Of course I can try to find and replace what I need, but I wasn't sure if there was an easy CLI command built in to AWSTATS similar to this:

awstats.pl -config LogFile="C:\path\to\log\file"

I intend to write a batch script which would change the option and then update the AWSTATS db during end of day processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realized AWSTATS provides tags which you can use to dynamically represent the date which means you don't have to manually change the date each day (whether it be with custom code or actually changing the `LogFile` path each day).

```
# "LogFile" contains the web, ftp or mail server log file to analyze.
# Possible values: A full path, or a relative path from awstats.pl directory.
# Example: "/var/log/apache/access.log"
# Example: "../logs/mycombinedlog.log"
# You can also use tags in this filename if you need a dynamic file name
# depending on date or time (Replacement is made by AWStats at the beginning
# of its execution). This is available tags :
#   %YYYY-n  is replaced with 4 digits year we were n hours ago
#   %YY-n    is replaced with 2 digits year we were n hours ago
#   %MM-n    is replaced with 2 digits month we were n hours ago
#   %MO-n    is replaced with 3 letters month we were n hours ago
#   %DD-n    is replaced with day we were n hours ago
#   %HH-n    is replaced with hour we were n hours ago
#   %NS-n    is replaced with number of seconds at 00:00 since 1970
#   %WM-n    is replaced with the week number in month (1-5)
#   %Wm-n    is replaced with the week number in month (0-4)
#   %WY-n    is replaced with the week number in year (01-52)
#   %Wy-n    is replaced with the week number in year (00-51)
#   %DW-n    is replaced with the day number in week (1-7, 1=sunday)
#                              use n=24 if you need (1-7, 1=monday)
#   %Dw-n    is replaced with the day number in week (0-6, 0=sunday)
#                              use n=24 if you need (0-6, 0=monday)
#   Use 0 for n if you need current year, month, day, hour...
# Example: "/var/log/access_log.%YYYY-0%MM-0%DD-0.log"
# Example: "C:/WINNT/system32/LogFiles/W3SVC1/ex%YY-24%MM-24%DD-24.log"
# You can also use a pipe if log file come from a pipe :
# Example: "gzip -cd /var/log/apache/access.log.gz |"
# If there are several log files from load balancing servers :
# Example: "/pathtotools/logresolvemerge.pl *.log |"
```